# How to calculate TPR and FPR in Python without using sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, roc, auc, precision-recall

Initialize the list of lists:

```
data = [[1.0, 0.635165,0.0], [1.0, 0.766586,1.0], [1.0, 0.724564,1.0],
        [1.0, 0.766586,1.0],[1.0, 0.889199,1.0],[1.0, 0.966586,1.0],
        [1.0, 0.535165,0.0],[1.0, 0.55165,0.0],[1.0, 0.525165,0.0],
        [1.0, 0.5595165,0.0] ]
```

Create the Pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['y', 'prob','y_predict'])
```

Print data frame.

```
print(df)
```

For this data-set, I want to find:

1. Confusion matrix without using Sklearn
2. Numpy array of TPR and FPR without using Sklearn, for plotting ROC.

How to do this in python?

Comment: For the calculation of the confusion matrix you can take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61193476/11989081

Comment: @gflavia...thx dear

Comment: @gflavia...can you suggest for 2. Numpy array of TPR and FPR without using Sklearn, for plotting ROC.

Comment: Take a look at this for calculating TPR and FPR : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29910634/13149719

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can calculate the false positive rate and true positive rate associated to different threshold levels as follows:

```py
import numpy as np

def roc_curve(y_true, y_prob, thresholds):

    fpr = []
    tpr = []

    for threshold in thresholds:

        y_pred = np.where(y_prob >= threshold, 1, 0)

        fp = np.sum((y_pred == 1) & (y_true == 0))
        tp = np.sum((y_pred == 1) & (y_true == 1))

        fn = np.sum((y_pred == 0) & (y_true == 1))
        tn = np.sum((y_pred == 0) & (y_true == 0))

        fpr.append(fp / (fp + tn))
        tpr.append(tp / (tp + fn))

    return [fpr, tpr]
```

Answer (score 0):

... without *sklearn* python module:

1. Confusion matrix without using Sklearn

   - You can use the pandas_ml

     *from pandas_ml import ConfusionMatrix*
   - You can build your math formula for the Confusion matrix
2. About ROC you

   - see the python MatLab example solve on [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37110924/how-to-plot-roc-curve-with-matplotlib-python);
   - can build your array and use the np and build your source code using the math formula.

You can understand more if you take a look at these articles:

[logistic-regression-using-numpy](https://www.kaggle.com/mtax687/logistic-regression-using-numpy) - python examples regression;

[what-is-the-roc-curve](https://notmatthancock.github.io/2015/08/18/what-is-the-roc-curve.html) - theory;

[roc-curve-part-2-numerical-example](https://notmatthancock.github.io/2015/08/19/roc-curve-part-2-numerical-example.html) - python practice;

Comment: 1. I just need the function that can give me the NumPy array of TPR & FPR separately. I know how to plot ROC. I can use numpy.trapz(tpr_array, fpr_array) for the auc_score, if I had the required arrays.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know a specific function for these issues. The input data for arrays TPR an FRP give the graph for ROC. " I just need the function that can give me the NumPy array of TPR & FPR separately." - so you don't have input data and you don't know the theory.

Comment: it's ok, I got it. Thanks

Comment: no problem, give your vote and rate the answers for each response, this will help users to understand your problem into an area of answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

def calculate_cm(predicted, actual):
  fp = np.sum((y_pred == 1) & (y_true == 0))
  tp = np.sum((y_pred == 1) & (y_true == 1))

  fn = np.sum((y_pred == 0) & (y_true == 1))
  tn = np.sum((y_pred == 0) & (y_true == 0))
  return tp, fp, fn, tn

def calculate_recall(tp, fp, fn, tn):
  return (tp)/(tp + fn)

def calculate_fallout(tp, fp, fn, tn):
  return (fp)/(fp + tn)

def calculate_at_threshold(threshold, actual, predicted):
  p = np.where(predicted >= threshold, 1, 0)
  tp, fp, fn, tn = calculate_cm(p, actual)
  tpr = calculate_recall(tp, fp, fn, tn)
  fpr = calculate_fallout(tp, fp, fn, tn)
  return fpr, tpr 

def roc_curve(actual, predicted, thresholds):
  tpr = []
  fpr = []
  for threshold in thresholds:
    fpr_t, tpr_t = calculate_at_threshold(threshold, actual, predicted)
    tpr.append(fpr_t)
    fpr.append(tpr_t)
  return fpr, tpr
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly faster version of Flavia Giammarino's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61323665/7976773) which only uses NumPy arrays; I also added a few comments and provided alternative, more generic variable names:

```
import numpy as np

def roc_curve(probabilities, ground_truth, thresholds):

    # Initialize FPR & TPR arrays
    fpr = np.empty_like(thresholds)
    tpr = np.empty_like(thresholds)

    # Compute FPR & TPR
    for t in range(0, len(thresholds)):
        y_pred = np.where(ground_truth >= thresholds[t], 1, 0)
        fp = np.sum((y_pred == 1) & (probabilities == 0))
        tp = np.sum((y_pred == 1) & (probabilities == 1))
        fn = np.sum((y_pred == 0) & (probabilities == 1))
        tn = np.sum((y_pred == 0) & (probabilities == 0))
        fpr[t] = fp / (fp + tn)
        tpr[t] = tp / (tp + fn)

    return fpr, tpr
```

Thresholds can be easily generated with a function like NumPy's [linspace](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html):

```
np.linspace(start, end, n)
```

where `[start, end]` is the thresholds' range (extremes included; should be `start = 0` and `end = 1`) and `n` is the number of thresholds; from experience I can say that `n = 50` is a good trade-off between speed and accuracy, although `n >= 100` yields smoother curves.